# Wifi doesn't always connect on 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04

When I boot Ubuntu 14.04, wifi doesn't always connect. It means that it works fine once in 3 reboots, but if it doesn't connect, I can't make it work just with a reboot. When the connection is established it remains stable. Of course everything worked fine with the previous version, this whole thing started after I upgraded.

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521, my lspci output for wireless is

> 08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Have you seen such a problem? Do you have any ideas how to troubleshoot or debug this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution ?